Numbering for multibib headers in table of contents
I'm using multibib to create three separate bibliographies as such:
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{xparse}
\newcites{A}{First}
\newcites{B}{Second}
\newcites{C}{Third}

My text entry at the end of my document is as follows:
\section{Bibliography}

\bibliographystylehai{apacite}
\bibliographyhai{bib/A}

\bibliographystylecpr{apacite}
\bibliographycpr{bib/B}

\bibliographystyleimp{apacite}
\bibliographyimp{bib/C}

In my table of contents, I get the listing of the section headers without numbers.

Would it be possible to include it under the Bibliography section (5.1 First ...) , or present it in a cohesive way?
